# .htaccess remove .php but add a / at the end

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have some code added to my .htaccess file and it works as intended.

```
RewriteEngine On

# hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

For example I have = http://www.hello.com/world.php

This code removed the php and will look like this http://www.hello.com/world

I want it to look like this = http://www.hello.com/world/

How do I add the / to the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Remember to fix `.php` to `\.php` as `filephp` would otherwise match.